# Extract part of a URL

Tags: javascript

I need to extract the `hello/world` part of this URL:

```
http://example.com/#tags/hello/world
```

I'm totally confussed with split, replace and concat. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: How dynamic does the remove need to be? Is the `http://example.com/#tags/` always the same and always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Jimmie - good question, but even if it is a fixed prefix it would be bad practise to hard code the prefix into the code.  Good code would decompose the URL and then only parse the anchor portion.

Comment: @Alnitak, that's exactly why I asked. You're answer was the solution I was considering posting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
function removePrefix(prefix,s) {
    return s.substr(prefix.length);
}
removePrefix('http://example.com/#tags/','http://example.com/#tags/hello/world')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = "http://example.com/#tags/hello/world".replace("http://example.com/#tags/","");
```

For the fastest way use this

```
var result = "http://example.com/#tags/hello/world".slice(25);
```

Comment: Your solution does not force the `http://...` to be the prefix. It is also less efficient than substring operation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this:

```
var newString = oldString.replace('http://example.com/#tags/', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

if this code is intended to working on the *current* page's URL you can use the `window.location.hash` property to just get the anchor portion of the URL and take everything after the first forward-slash:

```
var h = window.location.hash;
var p = h.substring(h.indexOf('/') + 1);
```

[NB: this will fail if there is no forward-slash in the anchor]

If instead you need to do this for a URL which you've currently only got in a string variable you can get some help from your browser's own URL parser by creating a detached DOM element and reading its properties:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://example.com/some/path/#tags/hello/world';

// a.hash now contains '#tags/hello/world'
var h = a.hash;
var p = h.substring(h.indexOf('/') + 1);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/xsEUW/ for a demo.

Comment: window.location.hash did not work, but window.location.href worked. My browser was Chrome 100.0.4896.75

Comment: Also to get the last index of / we can use lastindexof
 h.substring(h.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/http:\/\/example\.com\/#tags\//, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split creates an array out of a string using a character as a delimiter. 
so that is not really what you want, since you're trying to keep the end of the string, including what would be the natural delimiter.

substr removes the first n characters of a string. 
so you could do

```
var remove_string = 'http://example.com/#tags/'
path.substr(remove_string.length);
```

and it would work just fine.

Replace finds a given regular expression and replaces it with the second argument.
so you could also do (note that the regular expression is contained within / /)

```
path = path.replace(/^http:\/\/example.com\/#tags\//,"")
```

A little uglier because of the escaping of characters but a bit more succinct.

Also as a previous poster did you could just pass the string to be matched to replace instead of the regex.

Answer (score -1):

If we suppose http://example.com/#tags/ is the fixed part and the rest is variable
.

You could do the following

> var content='http://example.com/#tags/hello/world';
>   
>   var indicator='#tags';
>   
>   var result=content.substring(content.indexOf(indicator)+indicator.length);

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers. They'll help me a lot. One thing I don't understand is why the alert isn't triggered: `function filter(mystring){
var newString = mystring.replace('http://www.example.com/#tags/', '');
alert(newString);
 }` Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. What do I need to change exactly?

Comment: @Michael sorry misunderstood your comment .... your function is working fine what input did you provide ?

Comment: Thank you all for the great help!