# Extract a part from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url, extract

I have a string:

```
http://a.long.url/can/be/here/jquery.min.js?207
```

I need to extract the base URL `http://a.long.url/can/be/here/` using Javascript. So it should be split on the first `/` from the right.

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455555/extract-part-of-a-url

Comment: Then try `str.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
var url = 'http://a.long.url/can/be/here/jquery.min.js?207';
var path = url.split( '/' );
var stripped = "";
for ( i = 0; i < path.length-1; i++ ) {
    if(i>0) stripped += "/";
    stripped += path[i];
}
alert(stripped)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Remove the `+ 1` if you don't want the / in the end.

Comment: Note that this returns an empty string if the url does not contain a `/`, e.g. if it's simply `www.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://my.com:8080/path/bob.js?query"

var col1 = url.indexOf("?");
if (col1 > 0) {
    var col = url.substring(0,col1).lastIndexOf("/");
} else {
    col = url.lastIndexOf("/");
}

var extracted = url.substring(0, col);
```

Without checking for errors. (For example, what if the `url` string has no slashes at all. It's not a valid URL but it could be passed to this code.) Note also that it doesn't work if the question mark is the first character.